# React material-ui Stepper orientation Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My Stepper component should render in a vertical or horizontal layout depending on screen size. For that reason I'm using a prop "verticalLayout". If I render it in vertical mode (verticalLayout = {true}) everything seems to be working just fine. As soon as I render in horizontal mode (verticalLayout = {false}) it stops working with the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null`

My search didn't yield any answers and I tried everything I could think of (replacing this with a let variable, refactoring the code to check if this && this.props ... etc.) but only deleting all the references to  in the vertical Layout gets rid of the error. I'm at a loss and would greatly appreciate your help. Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
  Step,
  Stepper,
  StepLabel,
  StepContent,
} from 'material-ui/Stepper';

export default class MyReactiveStepperComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    console.info(this.props.verticalLayout)
    return (
      <div>
        <Stepper activeStep={this.props.activeStep} orientation={this.props.verticalLayout ? "vertical" : "horizontal"}>
          <Step>
            <StepLabel>Step 1</StepLabel>
            { console.warn(this.props) && this.props.verticalLayout &&
            <StepContent>
              {this.props.children}
            </StepContent>
            }
          </Step>
          <Step>
            <StepLabel>Step 2</StepLabel>
            { this.props.verticalLayout &&
            <StepContent>
              {this.props.children}
            </StepContent>
            }
          </Step>
          <Step>
            <StepLabel>Step 3</StepLabel>
            { this.props.verticalLayout &&
            <StepContent>
              {this.props.children}
            </StepContent>
            }
          </Step>
          <Step>
            <StepLabel>Step 4</StepLabel>
            { this.props.verticalLayout &&
            <StepContent>
              {this.props.children}
            </StepContent>
            }
          </Step>
        </Stepper>
        { !this.props.verticalLayout && <div> { this.props.children } </div> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the following :

```
{ this.props.verticalLayout &&
  <StepContent>
    {this.props.children}
  </StepContent>
}
```

I am not a JavaScript expert but I think that 'this' is not correctly bound to your `MyReactiveStepperComponent`.
You can work this around by using the ES6 arrow function syntax :

```
{
  () => this.props.verticalLayout && (
    <StepContent>
        {this.props.children}
    </StepContent>
  )
}
```

Or binding the calls to `this`, which is not recommanded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but there is an open discussion on the Github page about it:

[Stepper: Allow null children #6004](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/6004)

In a pinch, you might consider writing a renderStepChildren() function that dynamically adds the StepContent. Something like this (untested):

```
renderStepChildren = (verticalLayout) => {
  const children = [];

  children.push(<StepLabel key={0}>...</StepLabel>);
  if (verticalLayout) {
    children.push(<StepContent key={1}>...</StepContent>);
  }

  return children;
};
```

Then, in your render() method:

```
<Step>
  {this.renderStepChildren(this.props.verticalLayout)}
</Step>
```